# Create my personal browser language

Tags: html, browser, tags

Is there any way that I can create my own browser language (eg. html) that can be supported?

I have the above idea in mind but don't know how to work it out:
using XML with namespace?
JavaScript to do the function on the back-ends?
CSS for displaying content?

Comment: @sp00m He has an idea for this neat round, rolling structure.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "browser language". What kind of data do you want to store and present? Maybe there already exists some XML-dialect which suits you needs…

Comment: To simplify the html document. Such as using <CD title="my Title" id="123"></CD> for displaying a set of CD data in an clear way.

Comment: The question is still very vague. How should the element `<CD title="my Title" id="123"></CD>` be displayed? Should it have some functionality, such as playing a CD when clicked on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be possible with xml + xslt, yes.

Comment: Am I write some thing like this with xml + xslt?
<html>
<body>
<CD id="1" src="a.jpg"></CD>
<CD id="2" src="b.jpg"></CD>
</body>
<html>

Comment: You'll need to include a pointer to your xslt transformation to HTML somewhere (server configuration, processing instruction, …). Also, you will need to write the xslt transformation in the first place. But then, sure.